# How to make CMake recurse OBJECT libraries from subdirectories?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project set up like so:

```
rootdir/
rootdir/A
rootdir/A/B
```

Each directory has its own CMakeFiles.txt

In rootdir/A/B it does

```
add_library(A-B OBJECT <files here>)
```

In rootdir/A it does

```
add_subdirectory(B/)
add_library(A OBJECT <files here>)
target_link_libraries(A PUBLIC A-B)
```

In rootdir/ it does

```
add_subdirectory(A/)
add_library(rootlib STATIC <files here>)
target_link_libraries(rootlib PUBLIC A)
```

So the dependency library name DAG goes: `rootlib -> A -> A-B`

As it turns out, I checked using `nm ... --demangle` and `ar -t` and other tools, rootlib only contains `A` library object files, it did not recurse into `A-B`. I get tons of undefined symbol errors from the linker when I write tests linking to rootlib.a - the .o symbols from `A-B` aren't there.

Why isn't CMake recursing the library dependencies and making rootlib link all the .o's from the subdirectories? Am I missing something obvious here?

When I explicitly link rootlib with all subdirectory library names it works fine. But I assumed CMake would recurse *automagically* and link the rootlib.a with all dependent .o's so I didn't have to do it explicitly.

I'm aware that if I make those libraries .a (STATIC) instead of OBJECT, this would work, but I don't want a .a per directory. I'd like to recurse .o object files and then link it all at once.

I'm using `ninja` version 1.8.2 generator and `cmake` version 3.13.4

Comment: From the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#linking-object-libraries), "*Object Libraries may “link” to other object libraries to get usage requirements, but since they do not have a link step nothing is done with their object files.*" CMake object libraries do not support the recursive behavior you describe.

Comment: Thank you @squareskittles - I hadn't seen that. What does "link to other object libraries to get usage requirements" mean?

Comment: The meaning is explained (with an example) in the "**Linking Object Libraries**" section that I provided in my previous comment. Usage requirements refers to compile definitions and other flags that are needed by the lower level object libraries that get propagated to the higher level libraries (e.g. `rootlib`). If there are multiple levels of object libraries "linking" to other object libraries, only the usage requirements will be propagated through the entire chain.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.